# Problems with function isin, problem with number, with words working normaly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with function:

```
print(df.loc[df['Kriterij1'] == '63'])
```

and i was tried with (the same)

```
df[df.Kriterij1.isin(['aaa','63'])]
```

When I want to try  filtered by numbers the output is only the head (empty cells) its work only for word 'aaa'.
Or maybe i can use anoter function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need change `'63'` (string) to `63` (number), if mixed numeric with strings values:

```
print(df.loc[df['Kriterij1'] == 63])
print(df[df.Kriterij1.isin(['aaa',63])])
```

Comment: It works, thank you again. The problem was that the first I  use CSV file and then i was tried with xlsx.